# Best approach to handle "custom" (unknown) Java class

Tags: java

I am implementing kind of an online programming competition in and for Java. The idea is that a participant of the competition writes a controller for the application and sends it to the competition server. That custom controller has to be derived from an API's base class.

Ok, so all participants can write their own controller class, probabily also including other custom classes, and since the controller's main class is derived from an API's (abstract) base class, the application on the server can easily call a specific method of the child class (i.e. the custom controller) in a certain intervall in order to control the application.

My question now is: do you have any suggestions how I should handle this scenario from the API's perspective, so that it allows for a convenient way to dynamically load the custom controller implementation?

What I want to avoid is that the participants would need to include the API jar file into their Java project (e.g. in Eclipse), then write their controller class, put all into an executable jar again and upload it to the competition server. I definitely do not want to execute a fully custom application on the server.

I rather want to let the participants upload only their custom controller class. Then on the server this class should be automatically loaded in and as part of the application. I basically see two options here:

1. upload compiled .class file to the server; or
2. upload Java source code file, then compile on server

Which of these two options would you suggest, and why?
Or: do you have another, better alternative?

Moreover, how should I handle uploads of multiple classes? If possible I would like to allow the participants to write additional utility classes beside the main controller class.

Thanks in advance for all your ideas!

Comment: Why don't you want to take a JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, having the developer including the API jar in their Eclipse project does not imply that you need to run it as a full application.  You SHOULD in fact give the API jar to developer.  However, developer should provide you a JAR with ONLY their self-developed class.

I'd suggest not taking the approach of "receive the source code and compile on server".  It is simply making the situation unnecessarily complicated.

After your server received the JAR, you can simply create corresponding classloader to load their code.

Next question is: How do you know which class to load from their JAR?

There are lots of way to do so, here I am suggesting two easiest way:

1) Similar to @ChrisGerken suggested, have a "deployment descriptor".  A Deployment Descriptor, in a simplified view, is simply a text file with predefined format, in a predefined location.  Your code can read this file from the JAR provided, and you can ask the developer to put the class name (of their implementation class) in the descriptor, and you can easily instantiate their class, through reflection.

2) Another approach is something similar to how SLF4J load their adapter: Developer should make their implementation using a predefined classname, in a predefined package.  You can easily create the implementation class by reflection, and you save the step in reading the descriptor file.  However you lost the flexibility.

Both way should work.  Choose one that suit your need  (I will suggest pick 2 first, and you can add support of 1 later)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will give option 2 a try, probably also option 1 later on as well, as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern used by web servers, Eclipse and other platforms is to specify a deployment descriptor (usually an XML file) by specifying its schema.  The deployment descriptor in your case would identify the name of a jar file (usually in the same directory as the deployment descriptor) and the fully qualified name of the Java class (the custom controller in this case).

You write a program that reads a deployment descriptor to discover the name of the jar file (which you access via a class loader) and the name of the customer controller (which you load using the class loader).

This lets you take in as many entries as you like, each contained in its own directory.

You could even get fancy by having the deployment descriptor be a file with a well defined name in the jar itself, making the jar a fully conained entry.